# Select nodes that have specific descendants

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have an xhtml page containing multiple divs.
This:

```
 <xsl:template match="div[@class = 'toc']">
```

selects divs that interest me (all of them contain unordered lists - ul). Now I would like to select only those divs that contain two levels of ul elements.

In general: how do I select nodes that have specific type of children?

I tried something like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="body/div[@class = 'toc']/ul/li/ul" />

                   ...

<xsl:template match="div[@class = 'toc']/ul/li/ul">    
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="final_template" select="../../.."/> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="final_template" match="div">
        ...
</xsl:template>
```

But it doesn't work. What is more I believe there must be a cleaner approach to this problem than mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, to select nodes that have certain children:

```
NodeToSelect[childName]
```

To select nodes that have certain descendants:

```
NodeToSelect[.//descendantName]
```

Please try this path for your situation:

```
div[@class = 'toc'][.//ul//ul]
```

For the XSLT, this is probably a good way to go:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="body/div[@class = 'toc'][.//ul//ul]" mode="twoUlDescendants" />

                   ...

<xsl:template match="div" mode="twoUlDescendants">    
   <!-- Work with div here. -->
</xsl:template>
```

You can change the name of the mode "twoUlDescendants" to something that more accurately describes the purpose of these particular divs.